# Is it possible for a website to get information about you through its upload feature?

Tags: web-browser, file-upload

Reddit has a new image upload feature that takes a very long time to work after you click submit-- as long as 30 seconds. It isn't caused by the upload itself; that happens very quickly. I don't know what it is, and it makes me nervous, so I thought I would ask.

Could Reddit be doing something with the upload feature that could glean information about me that it couldn't through ordinary browsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A browser does not leak information apart from the selected file(s) and the information that can be accessed using JavaScript WebRTC etc. anyways when using the HTML file upload input.
There might be some calculations going on in the background like calculating CRC's until you're able to submit the form.